# Why is my overlay disappearing in Google Maps API in JS in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova

My app is showing an overlay. It works fine on Android and in browsers, but on iOS (using Cordova), the overlay sometimes disappears when I zoom or pan. Here's my onAdd() and draw().

```
function onAdd() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.opacity = this.isAdminMode ? '0.5' : '1';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
  div.appendChild(img);
  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

function draw() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + this.rot + 'deg)';
};
```

I've tried all sorts of things in these two functions and elsewhere, including unattaching/reattaching the map, repeatedly drawing, logging to check for wrong sw/ne coordinates -- nothing. And it works perfectly in anything other than iOS.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I found this 2012 archive post in Google Code:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/176

The gist of which is that there's a really long-standing bug in iOS that causes this, and the workaround is to add a CSS style,

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

to the thing that disappears. And that solves it.

So, to fix my code from the question, I added the *** line as shown below.

```
function onAdd() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.opacity = this.isAdminMode ? '0.5' : '1';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
  img.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translateZ(0px)';  // disappearing fix ***
  div.appendChild(img);
  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
```